# How do I get permission to save to the C drive in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

Does anyone know how to get permission to save directly to the C drive?
For our Payroll and E@syFile to work it requires you to save the Payroll File in the c drive.
When Importing the file into E@syFile, it tells you that it will only accept files that are saved on the c drive.  I can cut the file from another folder and then save it in the c drive, but then it doesn't want to upload correctly into the SARS E@syFile.

This will cause a lot of Bookkeepers hassles, as we have to then manually enter each IRP5 Certificate.

Answer (score 1):

try start your program **Payroll and E@syFile** by right click, **Run as Administrator**. See if this can grant permission for your program so it can save to C drive

---

How about right click your program, choose properties, security tab, in Group and User name, highlight your login account, edit it to grant full control permission

Comment: Thanks, but that still doesn't work :-(